# How to complement eMail notifications with a notification bar?

Tags: 7, notifications

I am building a Drupal 7 website, and I noticed that you can install a facebook-like chat. This made me wonder if it is possible to implement something related to notifications that works something like Facebook. I simply want the notification "bar" to tell me if a user is posting a comment on my website, or if a new user has signed up. At this moment I just get an email about users trying to sign up.

I looked at the [Notifications](https://www.drupal.org/project/notifications) module for D7, but I am not sure this is what I am looking for. Or maybe I just don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be looking for [Heartbeat](https://drupal.org/project/Heartbeat) module:

> Heartbeat displays user activity on a website. This module is an API to log activity. The logged data contains message structures, attributes and variables. Once the activity messages exist in the database, they will be parsed and build into activity streams.
>
> (...)
>
> Heartbeat has global configuration for display, message template configuration and stream configuration.

Comment: nice .. this is just what i am looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Since you already get a notification when users sign up, for comment notification you can use [Comment notify module](https://drupal.org/project/comment_notify)

> Notifies administrator (site_mail) of new user registrations. Starting
>   with Version 1.2 you can now define both the address it goes to and
>   the subject and messages emailed. Starting with 1.8 you can get emails
>   when someone updates their profile as well. Starting with 1.11 you can
>   use actual profile pieces not just a list of them all. Example if you
>   have a profile_name you would insert in the template !profile_name and
>   the value of profile_name will be inserted.

Any other notifications can be achieved using rules

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast and accurate instructions! Is there not a way to make the notifications display on the website (like fb) instead of getting them on a email?

Comment: I am afraid I do not know any way of doing that without having to write a custom module. The module that come closest to it are prowl and push notification modules. But they are used for pushing notifications to Phones

Comment: Ah, thanks alot. The best alternative i found is "user notifications" but its only for D6> . anyway i will have to do with this method.

Answer (score 2):

You should go for [Message](https://drupal.org/project/message) module which is an advanced module for messaging and notification and maintained actively.

> Message module is Drupal 7's answer to activity-streams and a flexible
>   Messaging & Notifications system.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of Rules, [Messages to Block](https://drupal.org/project/messages_to_block) and [Menu Badges](https://drupal.org/project/menu_badges)  modules does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Menu Badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_badges) module for such notifications, which you can add to any **menu item** and/or **menu tab** of your choice. In your case something like "***New comments***" seems like one, out of a few, appropriate menu item (or menu tab).

Here are some details about it (from its project page):

> Provides a method for adding iOS-style badges to menu items. (see screenshot)
>
> [image]
>
> #### Adding Badges to Menus
>
> Once enabled, go to `Administration > Structure > Menus`, and click "list links" next to the menu containing the target item. Click "edit" next to the item and select the badge to display with the Display Menu Badge select box.
>
> #### Adding Badges to Tabs
>
> For adding badges to menu tabs, there is a tab under `Administration > Structure > Menus` called "Tab Menu Badges". Search for the menu router path of the tab you want to alter, then select a badge from the corresponding select box.
>
> #### Badge Types
>
> The module includes five example badges, and new badges can be created easily with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). Modules can also supply their own badges with a hook implementation. See the [README.txt](http://drupalcode.org/project/menu_badges.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/README.txt) file for details.

Because of how it integrates with the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module, by using this integration you basically reduce the solution for any type of notification to something like "Just create an appropriate view of it".

However, there is a small caveat: if you really want the actual number (shown in the red circle) to be accurate, make sure you have some field in your view that will actually correspond to the "`new`" part of your question. To better explain this: have a look at the "`tracker`" view (disabled by default), which has the field "***Content:Has new content***" (or variation: "***Content:Has new comments***"). This is a perfect field to use if you want to use [Menu Badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_badges) to get notified whenever there is new content (or variation: new comments).

If you don't have such "new" indicator, then you basically have 2 variations to get around that:

- You give the user the option to selectively mark those entries so that they are no longer included in the counter. It takes a little effort to implement such option, but the tutorial about "[How to allow users to manage their own Message Stack messages?"](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/82) explains how to use the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag), [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) modules to get it to work.
- When the user visits the menu link (or menu tab), you "mark" all of the entries included in the Menu Badges counter as "no longer new". That should make the counter disappear entirely. The anser to "[How to make menu badges count disappear after the page is viewed?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/210986/how-to-make-menu-badges-count-disappear-after-the-page-is-viewed/212383#212383)" details the steps how this can be implemented.

#### Video tutorials:

- [Defining Menu Badges with Views in Drupal](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AoZQNg5QOI), from the module maintainer, which shows how to use it for a custom view with a menu tab "unpublished content" within `admin/content`.
- [Drupal 7 Menu Badges Module](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=iz25ED1ECv8).