# What may cause my custom VBO action to no longer update my Menu Badges counter?

Tags: 7, rules, views, notifications

I created a on-site notification system with the help of this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/210986/how-to-make-menu-badges-count-disappear-after-the-page-is-viewed). It was working perfectly, but now suddenly it stopped working. When I visit the page, the menu badge does not disappear.

Recently, I updated the core. Not sure if this is the problem. When I visit the page [www.mysite.com/notification](http://www.example.com/notification), the log shows following errors.

[image: errors]

Following is my views, rule and rule component

**Views Export**

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'notifications';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'message';
$view->human_name = 'Notifications';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Notifications';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: Message: User uid */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['id'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['field'] = 'user';
/* Relationship: Flags: message_viewed */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['id'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['field'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['required'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['flag'] = 'message_viewed';
/* Field: Message: Message ID */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['id'] = 'mid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['field'] = 'mid';
/* Field: Message: Render message (Get text) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['id'] = 'message_render';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['field'] = 'message_render';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['partials'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['partials_delta'] = '0';
/* Field: Message: Timestamp */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['date_format'] = 'html5_tools_iso8601';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['second_date_format'] = 'html5_tools_iso8601';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Bulk operations: Message */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['id'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['table'] = 'views_entity_message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['field'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['label'] = 'Mark as read';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['display_type'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['enable_select_all_pages'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['row_clickable'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['force_single'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['entity_load_capacity'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_operations'] = array(
  'rules_component::rules_flag_a_message' => array(
    'selected' => 1,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'skip_permission_check' => 0,
    'override_label' => 1,
    'label' => 'Mark selected message(s) as read',
  ),
);
/* Sort criterion: Message: Timestamp */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Contextual filter: Message: User uid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['id'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['field'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['default_argument_type'] = 'current_user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';

/* Display: All */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'All', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['relationships'] = FALSE;
/* Relationship: Message: User uid */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['id'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['field'] = 'user';
/* Relationship: Flags: message_viewed */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['id'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['field'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['required'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['flag'] = 'message_viewed';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Message: Message ID */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['id'] = 'mid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['field'] = 'mid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Message: Render message (Get text) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['id'] = 'message_render';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['field'] = 'message_render';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['partials'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['partials_delta'] = '0';
/* Field: Message: Timestamp */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['date_format'] = 'html5_tools_iso8601';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['second_date_format'] = 'html5_tools_iso8601';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Flags: Flagged time */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['id'] = 'timestamp_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['table'] = 'flag_content';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['relationship'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['date_format'] = 'html5_tools_iso8601';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['second_date_format'] = 'html5_tools_iso8601';
/* Field: Bulk operations: Message */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['id'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['table'] = 'views_entity_message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['field'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['display_type'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['enable_select_all_pages'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['row_clickable'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['force_single'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['entity_load_capacity'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_operations'] = array(
  'rules_component::rules_flag_a_message' => array(
    'selected' => 1,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'skip_permission_check' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'notification';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Notifications';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['name'] = 'main-menu';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context_only_inline'] = 0;

/* Display: Read */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Read', 'page_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Message: Message ID */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['id'] = 'mid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['field'] = 'mid';
/* Field: Message: Render message (Get text) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['id'] = 'message_render';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['field'] = 'message_render';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['partials'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['partials_delta'] = '0';
/* Field: Message: Timestamp */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['date_format'] = 'html5_tools_iso8601';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['second_date_format'] = 'html5_tools_iso8601';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Flags: Flagged time */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['id'] = 'timestamp_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['table'] = 'flag_content';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['relationship'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['date_format'] = 'html5_tools_iso8601';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['second_date_format'] = 'html5_tools_iso8601';
/* Field: Bulk operations: Message */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['id'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['table'] = 'views_entity_message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['field'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['label'] = 'Mark as unread';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['display_type'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['enable_select_all_pages'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['row_clickable'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['force_single'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['entity_load_capacity'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Flags: Flagged */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['id'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['table'] = 'flag_content';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['field'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['relationship'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'notification/read';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Read';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['name'] = 'main-menu';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context_only_inline'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['tab_options']['weight'] = '0';

/* Display: Unread */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Unread', 'page_2');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Flags: Flagged */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['id'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['table'] = 'flag_content';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['field'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['relationship'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['value'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'notification/unread';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Unread';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context_only_inline'] = 0;

/* Display: Unread badge */
$handler = $view->new_display('menu_badge', 'Unread badge', 'menu_badge_1');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: Flags: message_viewed */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['id'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['field'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['required'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['flag'] = 'message_viewed';
/* Relationship: Message: User uid */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['id'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['field'] = 'user';
/* Field: Message: Message ID */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['id'] = 'mid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['field'] = 'mid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['group_type'] = 'count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['hide_empty'] = TRUE;
/* Contextual filter: Message: User uid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['id'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['field'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['default_argument_type'] = 'current_user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Filter criterion: Flags: Flagged */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['id'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['table'] = 'flag_content';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['field'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['relationship'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['value'] = '0';
```

**Rule Export**

```
{ "rules_mark_all_unread_messages_read" : {
    "LABEL" : "Mark all unread messages read",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "views_bulk_operations" ],
    "ON" : { "init" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "2" : "2" } }
        }
      },
      { "text_matches" : {
          "text" : [ "site:current-page:url" ],
          "match" : "notification",
          "operation" : "regex"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "views_bulk_operations_action_load_list" : {
          "USING" : { "view" : "notifications|page" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_list" : { "unread_msgs_list" : "A list of unreadmessages" } }
        }
      },
      { "LOOP" : {
          "USING" : { "list" : [ "unread-msgs-list" ] },
          "ITEM" : { "current_msg" : "Current message" },
          "DO" : [
            { "component_rules_flag_a_message" : { "message_to_flag" : [ "current-msg" ] } }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Rule Component**

```
{ "rules_flag_a_message" : {
    "LABEL" : "Flag a message",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "flag" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "message_to_flag" : { "label" : "Message to be flagged", "type" : "message" } },
    "DO" : [
      { "flag_flagmessage" : {
          "flag" : "message_viewed",
          "message" : [ "message-to-flag" ],
          "flagging_user" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "permission_check" : "1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Even though I don't know the exact answer yet, I think this is a great example of a high quality (well documented) question, chapeau (heads off!) Umair!

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Can you please edit the question heading? I think it needs some editing. Something like "Views update failing rules and vbo execution". Not sure

Comment: How about "What may cause my custom VBO action to no longer update my Menu Badges counter?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"***... it suddenly it stopped working***" are about the toughest support calls to be resolved. I bet something did change somehow/somewhere (intentionally or not doesn't matter), so give it a try to narrow down the actual issue, as detailed below ...

#### Narrowing down the actual problem

From the error log you posted in your question, and based on what is shown in the exported view and rule, it is clear (at least to me) that the cause of your issue is related to the very first rules action, which is the only place where you have that `unread_msgs_list` (as shown in the error message also).

Furthermore, that `/notification` path is what I can see in your exported view, and which actually corresponds to the custom VBO action you implemented with the rule in your question also (which in turn invokes the subsequent Rules Component).

#### Recommended debugging

Something that might help you find the answer to your question, is to have a look at [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) **debugging** ... Within the Rules **settings**, experiment a bit with the debugging facilities that come with the rules module. At least have a look at the "***Rules Evaluation Log***" (to check that the Rules logic being executed, actually matches what you expect that logic to be).

Depending on what the result of that type of debugging is, you may also want to (temporary) enable the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module, so that you can (temporary) add a Rules Action like "Display a value" (though at this point I don't see any value worth displaying for debugging purposes, for that you first need to find anything suspicious in the Rules debugging log).

For way more details about these 2 variations, refer to **Rules debugging**, as explained in the answer to "[How can I display the value of a variable inside a condition?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199080/rules-debug-how-can-i-display-the-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-condition/199134#199134)".

PS 1: It might help if you add an update to your question, to include the complete message that starts with "`Unable to get unread_msgs_list, it is not ...`"

PS 2: You did a good job to implement what got suggested in the related post.

Answer (score 0):

Well fortunately I had a backup. Views 3.15 is seem to cause problems. The backup had 3.14. Now it is working. The above view might not work. Here is the export of my view in case anyone wants to create a notification system.

View Export

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'notifications';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'message';
$view->human_name = 'Notifications';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Notifications';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: Flags: message_viewed */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['id'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['field'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['required'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['flag'] = 'message_viewed';
/* Relationship: Message: User uid */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['id'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['field'] = 'user';
/* Field: Message: Message ID */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['id'] = 'mid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['field'] = 'mid';
/* Field: Bulk operations: Message */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['id'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['field'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['display_type'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['enable_select_all_pages'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['row_clickable'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['force_single'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['entity_load_capacity'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_operations'] = array(
  'rules_component::rules_flag_a_message' => array(
    'selected' => 1,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
);
/* Field: Message: Render message (Get text) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['id'] = 'message_render';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['field'] = 'message_render';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['partials'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['partials_delta'] = '0';
/* Field: Message: Timestamp */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['date_format'] = 'short';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['second_date_format'] = 'long';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Message: Timestamp */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['timestamp']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Contextual filter: Message: User uid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['id'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['field'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['default_argument_type'] = 'current_user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'notification';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['type'] = 'tab';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['title'] = 'Notifications';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['weight'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['name'] = 'main-menu';
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['menu']['context_only_inline'] = 0;

/* Display: unread */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'unread', 'page_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Message: Message ID */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['id'] = 'mid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['field'] = 'mid';
/* Field: Bulk operations: Message */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['id'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['field'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['display_type'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['enable_select_all_pages'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['row_clickable'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['force_single'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['entity_load_capacity'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_operations'] = array(
  'rules_component::rules_flag_a_message' => array(
    'selected' => 1,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
);
/* Field: Message: Render message (Get text) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['id'] = 'message_render';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['field'] = 'message_render';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['partials'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['partials_delta'] = '0';
/* Field: Message: Timestamp */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['date_format'] = 'short';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['second_date_format'] = 'long';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Flags: Flagged time */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['id'] = 'timestamp_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['table'] = 'flag_content';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['relationship'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['date_format'] = 'long';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp_1']['second_date_format'] = 'long';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Flags: Flagged */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['id'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['table'] = 'flag_content';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['field'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['relationship'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['value'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'notification/unread';

/* Display: read */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'read', 'page_2');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Message: Message ID */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['id'] = 'mid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['field'] = 'mid';
/* Field: Bulk operations: Message */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['id'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['field'] = 'views_bulk_operations';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['display_type'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['enable_select_all_pages'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['row_clickable'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['force_single'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_settings']['entity_load_capacity'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['views_bulk_operations']['vbo_operations'] = array(
  'rules_component::rules_flag_a_message' => array(
    'selected' => 1,
    'postpone_processing' => 0,
    'skip_confirmation' => 0,
    'override_label' => 0,
    'label' => '',
  ),
);
/* Field: Message: Render message (Get text) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['id'] = 'message_render';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['field'] = 'message_render';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['partials'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['message_render']['partials_delta'] = '0';
/* Field: Message: Timestamp */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['id'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['field'] = 'timestamp';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['date_format'] = 'short';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['timestamp']['second_date_format'] = 'long';
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filter_groups'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['filters'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Flags: Flagged */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['id'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['table'] = 'flag_content';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['field'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['relationship'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'notification/read';

/* Display: Menu badge */
$handler = $view->new_display('menu_badge', 'Menu badge', 'menu_badge_1');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: Message: User uid */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['id'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['user']['field'] = 'user';
/* Relationship: Flags: message_viewed */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['id'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['field'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['required'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['flag_content_rel']['flag'] = 'message_viewed';
/* Field: Message: Message ID */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['id'] = 'mid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['field'] = 'mid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['group_type'] = 'count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['mid']['empty_zero'] = TRUE;
/* Contextual filter: Message: User uid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['id'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['table'] = 'message';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['field'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['default_argument_type'] = 'current_user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['user']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Filter criterion: Flags: Flagged */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['id'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['table'] = 'flag_content';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['field'] = 'flagged';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['relationship'] = 'flag_content_rel';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['flagged']['value'] = '0';
```

Comment: Do you have an idea what exactly the difference in this exported view is, as compared to the one in your question? If so I suggest you add that to your own answer here ...